# Why $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a principal ideal ring (why my example is bad)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We know that $\mathbb{Z} [ x ]$ is not a principal ideal ring, because we can construct the ideal $\langle 2,x \rangle$. 
Why we couldn't take as an example of non-principal ideal in it all polynomials with the same given root $y$? i.e.
$$P(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0=(x-y)\cdot (\dots$$
$$P(x) \cdot Q(x)=(x-y)^2 \cdot \dots$$
$$P(x)+Q(x)=(x-y)(\dots)$$
So, $I$ is the ideal.
Am I right?

Comment: But it's principal.

Comment: Take $y=0$ and you'll see easily the ideal is principal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideal $I = \{ f \in {\mathbb Z}[x] \mid f(a) = 0 \}$ is principal: $I = \langle x - a \rangle$.

Comment: Thank you ;) I'm so inattentive... I'm so sorry for it.